# interactive shell or bash script to manipulate a text file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file that contains 2 columns( example below )

```
Account_name Device_name
12345 1a3T567890f2
```

Values of the Device_name column then needs to be changed to:

- Uppercase letters if letters exist (example `1A3T567890F2`)

  ```
  awk '{ print toupper($0) }' file.txt > file2.txt
  ```
- The Colon symbol needs to be inserted to separate the value in to 2 char
  chunks (example `1A:3T:56:78:90:F2`)

  ```
  sed 's/\(\w\w\)\(\w\w\)\(\w\w\)\(\w\w\)\(\w\w\)\(\w\w\)/\1:\2:\3:\4:\5:\6/g' file2.txt > file3.txt
  ```

I would like to create a script that does those two functions at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add `\U` at the start of your sed's replace expression to switch the following to uppercase :

```
sed 's/(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)/\U\1:\2:\3:\4:\5:\6/g' file2.txt > file3.txt
```

---

> Test run :
>
> ```
> $ echo "1a3T567890f2" | sed -r 's/(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)/\U\1:\2:\3:\4:\5:\6/g'
> 1A:3T:56:78:90:F2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything in `awk`:

```
awk '{$2=toupper($2);gsub(/[[:alnum:]]{2}/,"&:", $2);sub(/:[[:space:]]*$/,"",$2)}1' file
```

That's a bit more intuitive and it works for various amount of digits.

Comment: What means *it did not work*? If you use the example from your question it will work

Comment: correct hek2mgl, using my example turns letters uppercase  but if I use yours it just adds | at the end of line

this is what I run: so please correct me if i utilise your command incorrectly. Thanks

    awk -F'|' '{$2=toupper($2);gsub(/[[:alnum:]]{2}/,"&:", $2);sub(/:$/,"",$2)}1' OFS='|' file.txt > file1.txt

Comment: You called the command correctly. If you just put `12345|1a3T567890f2` into file, does it work?

Comment: I see where I confused you, please ignore | as this was a way for me to separate the two tables in my question...| should be 1 blank space

and yes, when i put | in between Account_name and Device_name it kind of works but it gives me additional colon symbol at the end which I don't need
12345|1A:3T:56:78:90:F2:

Comment: Ok. Looks like there is space after the last field in the input. Changed my command.